# How to update JSON data using input fields created using myData.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-hooks

The JSON data is used to create dynamic Input fields for each item in the array. I would like the JSON data to be updated to match the quantity selected but am unsure the best way to go about this?

I plan on using Hooks to initially store the number of items selected then update the JSON file with a button press, although I am very open to the JSON file updating onChange. what is the best practise for this can you dynamically create react hooks?

here is my current code(I want the quantity to update in the JSON file).

**JSON:**

```
//Json data for the shopping ingredients

export default [
    {
        bread: {
            Quantity: 0,
        },
        Name: 'Bread',
        Price: "1.10",
    },

    {
        milk: {
            Quantity: 0,
        },
        Name: 'Milk',
        Price: "0.50",
    },

    {
        cheese: {
            Quantity: 0,
        },
        Name: 'Cheese',
        Price: "0.90",
    },

    {
        soup: {
            Quantity: 0,
        },
        Name: 'Soup',
        Price: "0.60",
    },

    {
        butter: {
            Quantity: 0,
        },
        Name: 'Butter',
        Price: "1.20",
    }
]
```

**React:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Data from '../shoppingData/Ingredients';

const ShoppingPageOne = (props) => {

  //element displays
  const [pageone_show, setPageone_show] = useState("pageOne");

  //updates quatity of ingredients
  const [bread_quantity, setBread_quantity] = useState(0);
  const [milk_quantity, setMilk_quantity] = useState(0);
  const [cheese_quantity, setCheese_quantity] = useState(0);
  const [soup_quantity, setSoup_quantity] = useState(0);
  const [butter_quantity, setButter_quantity] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    //sets info text using Json
    if (props.showOne) {
      setPageone_show("pageOne");
    } else {
      setPageone_show("pageOne hide");
    }
  }, [props.showOne]);


  return (
    <div className={"Shopping_Content " + pageone_show}>
      {Data.map((Ingredients) => {
        return <div className="Shopping_input" key={Ingredients.Name}>
          <p>{Ingredients.Name} £{Ingredients.Price}</p>
          <input onChange={} type="number"></input>
        </div>
      })}
      <div className="Shopping_Buttons">
        <p onClick={props.next_ClickHandler}>Buy Now!</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingPageOne;
```

Having input fields generated dynamically from a JSON file is great but using static hooks to update the JSON seems rather silly.

Answer (score 0):

To work with a file system you need to have particular modules. You can do it using NodeJS using 'fs' module https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html.
You need a separate endpoint that will be responsible for data updating that will be on the server-side.

Comment: I don't quite understand maybe my explanation wasn't the best but what I'm trying to do should be possible just using javascript and react should it not?

Comment: Where do you store your JSON? And can you describe your application? Because it's not clear. In my view, you have a separate application for client-side and for server-side. Correct me if I'm wrong. So as I understood your JSON file is stored on the client-side. You can use data from JSON on the client-side, but you can't write smth and save these changes in the file system without NodeJS, because you don't have such API to work with file system in the browser. But if you use hybrid framework you can... It depends on you situanion... Can provide details, please?

Comment: The JSON file is stored locally you can see where it is imported at the top, someone on a different post solved my issue but than you anyway! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143385/how-do-i-create-a-new-json-object-inside-a-react-hook/65143583#65143583

Comment: Sorry, but you said that you want to "update in the JSON file", but in your link, the author updates data that he gets from JSON. :) I said that you can't write updated data in your existing JSON file without NodeJS because to do it you need API that you can get from NodeJS. So, anyway, just wanted to help :)

Comment: ah I see well what I have done is sufficient my fault sorry

Comment: It's OK :) Don't worry!